# android studio generate object from selected fields

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new with android studio and just come up with a question. I've searched online, but didn't find an answer. So, does anyone know if it is possible to generate a new class, like to get a prompt where i can enter class name and other details, from selected fields in another class (something like - select fields, right click etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you really meaning, but if you want to create a class and gave it details, you just need to right click in the java carpet, and click in class icon.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i'm asking about different thing. It is similar to "Generate Constructor", but i was looking for  "Generate Class" from selected fields.